# Haskell - fileManip find - ignoring directories when recursively searching not working

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to use the `FilePath.Find` function from FileManip to ignore recursion on certain directories.

E.g. I want to ignore directories ending in test, or ignore .git, etc.

Example: give me all files not in the stack-work dir or the web dir

```
import System.Directory
import System.Environment
import System.FilePath.Find
import System.FilePath.GlobPattern
import qualified Data.List as L
import Control.Monad

notIsSuffixOf :: [Char] -> [Char] -> Bool
notIsSuffixOf a b = not (L.isSuffixOf a b)

nots :: FindClause Bool
nots = (\d -> notIsSuffixOf "web" d || notIsSuffixOf "stack-work" d) `liftM` directory

findAllNots :: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]
findAllNots path = find nots (fileType ==? RegularFile) path
```

But it's definitely not ignoring the web or stack-work directories.  I've been wracking my brain on this but can't seem to figure it out. Doing them in isolation doesn't seem to work reliably either (doing just stack-work works, but `"web"` still matches `/blah/web/jds.txt` for example.

If I change it to `isSuffixOf` I match on nothing, which is also disconcerting.  Reading through http://hackage.haskell.org/package/filemanip-0.3.6.3/docs/System-FilePath-Find.html indicates that this should work, see top example where `` (isInfixOf "temp") `liftM` directory `` matches any directory with `temp`

Comment: Just a guess, but the doc for `directory` gives an example: `directory "foo/bar.txt" => "foo"`. If `nots` is getting passed the `web` directory, do you know if this is treated as a directory (the trailing slash is removed), or as a file (the `web` is removed and the comparison is done with the parent directory name)?

Comment: Oh, actually, I think you need to use `&&` instead of `||` in your `nots` definition. Right now `web` is passing `notIsSuffixOf "stack-work" d`, which is causing it to pass the filter, and vice versa.